# javascript inner loop causing outer for loop to stop after one iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a webpage open and am writing a script to auto-fill fields that were left blank by the user. The page has 2 types of controls, text and radio.

I have two arrays, one holding the text control IDs and one holding the radio control IDs. The function handling the radio controls is giving me fits. The radio controls array is 2 dimensional as the radio controls have 2 or more IDs. So I was thinking to have a nested FOR loop cycling thru the radio control IDs and then thru the sub-array checking each control if checked.

I run the code by putting it in an entry on my toolbar, the code goes in the URL.

If I take out the inner FOR loop the outer one goes thru completion, but with the inner code it stops after the 1st iteration.

I have limited js coding experience and just have been doing trial and error and lots of searching the net. Any help/guidance would be most appreciated!

```js
javascript: (function() {
  var TextControlIDs = ["q2471",
    "q2444",
    "q2447",
    "q2448",
    "q2449",
    "q2452",
    "q2453",
    "q2454",
    "q2459",
    "q2460",
    "q2461",
    "q2464",
    "q2465",
    "q2466",
    "q2467",
    "q2468"
  ];
  var RadioControlIDs = [
    ["q2439:1", "q2439:0"],
    ["q2440:1", "q2440:0"],
    ["q2441:1", "q2441:0"]
  ];


  tcontrols(TextControlIDs);
  rcontrols(RadioControlIDs);

})();

function tcontrols(TextControlIDs) {
  aLen = TextControlIDs.length;
  for (i = 0; i < aLen; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(TextControlIDs[i]).value == '')

    {
      document.getElementById(TextControlIDs[i]).value = 'NA - Script ended';
    }
  }
}

function rcontrols(RadioControlIDs) {

  var aLen = RadioControlIDs.length;
  var i;
  var j;
  var bFlag;
  var asublen;

  alert('aLen ' + aLen);

  for (i = 0; i < aLen; i++) {
    asublen = RadioControlIDs[i].length;
    bFlag = false;
    alert('asublen ' + asublen);
    alert('i ' + i);
    for (j = 0; j < asubLen; j++) {
      alert('j ' + j);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Posting the console output would have been great please...

Comment: You don't declare i in the first loop. Since you probably want your loop variables tightly scoped anyway, I'd write `for (var i=0; ......)`, so including the var keyword. In your code, at least in `tcontrols`, you make `i` a property of the global object.

Comment: Nothing in your inner (j) loop will cause your outer (i) loop to stop.  However, as @GolezTrol noted, you should be using `for (var i = 0...)` and `for (var j = 0...)` because your `i` and `j` are global scope.  Thus, other things in the code will affect them.  This is probably what is causing your issue.

Comment: You're using   `for (j = 0; j < asubLen; j++) {` but you've defined `asublen` -- no capital 'l' -- you should check the error console.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips. I did say I have limited js experience. I like strongly typing variables so will get on that. I knew js was case sensitive and just totally missed the variable name mis-match, guess just really needed a 2nd, 3rd, ...set of eyes. :-)

Comment: Guess I can use a pointer, Mark you mentioned checking the error console, where and how do I do that?